# CSS div to place image without interfering with other divs

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web site for my church. Because they know of no web programmer members, I am taking care of it with my meager skills. My problem is merely one of placement. I am trying to place an image in the top-left of the page, but, no matter what I do, it interferes with the other div elements on the page. This is my current CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div#wrapper {
width: 90%;
background-color:#ffffff;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0px;
border: thin solid blue;
}
div#image {
padding: 15px;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
}
div#header {
padding: 15px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
div#nav {
width: 25%;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 100px;
float: left;
}
div#main {
margin-left: 30%;
margin-top: 100px;
padding: 10px;
}
div#footer {
padding: 15px;
margin: 0px;
border-top: thin solid blue;
text-align: center;
}
```

No matter how I define the image div, it always pushes the main, navigation, and header divs out of alignment. If I just place the image in another div, it still makes things move.

Is there any way to have the page centered with 90% width and everything else in the wrapper div, and also have the image in the top-right corner? If it would require a different type of thing, can someone help me figure it out? Something that works only in one browser won't help, as I want it to work as seamlessly as possible for the most people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be looking to use absolute positioning,

```
#image { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

However this will need to stay relative to your wrapper:

```
#wrapper { position:relative; }
```

Though I'm strictly guessing, provide more info and you'll get a more definitive solution.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for, except is there any way to make the image be not at 0, 0, but 10, 10? I tried changing it to top:10;left:10; but it did not move at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index to put the image on a higher layer.

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

This way nothing else gets moved.

Comment: Assuming he's talking about #image it would first need a position other than static in order for the stacking order effect of z-index to take place.

Comment: That is true, I forgot to mention that part.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to affect anything else on the page, can I just check that it's not a background image? If it's not, then have you tried *making* it a background image? That way it won't/can't affect the document flow and nothing will be moved because of it.

Though if you already have one background image it might complicate things a little.